# How to Export Crystal report to PDF in local system?

Tags: crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

I need to export a crystal report to local System in `PDF` format.

I have used `ExporttoDesk` but it saved in Server.I need to make it available to the user.

Is it Possible ?

I used `ExporttoStream`.But its also not worked for me.

Please tell me the way to achieve this.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on Button's click

```
try
        {
            ExportOptions CrExportOptions ;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";
            CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
            }
            cryRpt.Export();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Read its explanation [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-export-pdf.htm)

Comment: Hi...This is a web Application,I have implemented your code but it didn't download any file

Answer (score 0):

**How to do it when we have parameters ?**

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim Report As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument()
        Report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"))
        Report.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "######", "IT250WS", "demo")
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnPDF_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim Report As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument()
        Report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"))
        Report.SetParameterValue("@EmpId", 1)
        Report.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "######", "IT250WS", "demo")
        Response.Buffer = False
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "File_Name")
        Response.[End]()
    End Sub
```

Comment: There is already an answer saying what you have provided. There's no reason to duplicate that answer.

Comment: @hongsy  here I am talking about with Parameter in questions he asking without parameter. I hope you understand and support me.

Answer (score -2):

It's too late for the answer, but it may be usefull for ohters like me.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument pdfReport = new ReportDocument();
        pdfReport.Load(Server.MapPath("ExportToPdf.rpt"));
        pdfReport.SetDatabaseLogon("amitjain","password", @"AMITJAIN\SQL", "Northwind");
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = pdfReport;
    }

    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument pdfReport = new ReportDocument();
        pdfReport.Load(Server.MapPath("ExportToPdf.rpt"));
        pdfReport.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", @"AMITJAIN\SQL", "Northwind");
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        pdfReport.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Employees");
        Response.End();
    }
```

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/01/export-crystalreports-to-pdf-word-excel.html

tested and working.

Comment: A [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).